# Displaying the state in a geochart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am displaying a GeoChart the state level. When configuring with the Brazil region works, as you can see below, but not with the state code, for example: `BR-SP`

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['BR-AL', 300],
    ['BR-SP', 300],
    ['BR-RJ', 400]

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    region: 'BR',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

A nível de estado:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['Sao Paulo', 300],
    ['Campinas', 300],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    region: 'BR-SP',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Ok. This is a mistake, but not a cause of problem. Removed line.

Comment: When I run the code snippet I can see the BR-SP region. Can you give more detail on your problem?

Comment: did you run second snippet? I receive --> `Requested map does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your `options.region`

```
var options = {
    region: 'BR-SP',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
}
```

Region subcodes don't seem to be allowed. According to the [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#Configuration_Options), the region code can only be

> The area to display on the map. (Surrounding areas will be displayed as well.) Can be either a country code (in uppercase ISO-3166 format), or a one of the following strings: ...

If you look at the [Wikipedia Article List of Country Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes), `BR-SP` is not included as it's a subdivision and doesn't have a numerical code attached (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:BR).

If you change the region to `BR` it'll work, but unfortunately It doesn't look like you can zoom in any further.

Check out [Leaflet Maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) (an open sourced alternative). You can use GeoJSON to set the regions and then do your own zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't divide a country region (e.g. São Paulo) in subregions (e.g. Campinas) using `options.displayMode: 'regions'` but you can show them as markers with `options.displayMode: 'markers'`

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['São Paulo', 300],
    ['Campinas', 200],
    ['Araras', 400],
    ['Buri', 100],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    region: 'BR',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Cláudio, i wanna make a division of states like that [example](https://leachcreative.com/demos/us-geochart). When click in state, zoom in  is apply for that region.